# scrapyd jobs are not running and some scrapyd jobs are not finishing

Tags: scrapyd

I have deployed some jobs on a couple of machines with crontab.
Recently, I have two problems.
1.Some problems happened on one of these machines:jobs are not running and staying in pending queue for a lot of days.
2.Unlike problem above, some jobs on another machine are staying with running status for more than 1 day. These jobs should finish in about less than one hour and their logs shows that they have finished already (most log files have been removed and a couple of log files of these jobs exist with content of finish notice).

jobs info shows below:

```
Project Spider  Job PID Runtime Log Items

Pending

weibo_spider    weibo_spider    b2fc68949b1311e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  wangyi_spider   0b449fdeac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  qq_spider   0dda73f4ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  infzm_spider    106cb1a4ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  china_spider    11424670ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  people_spider   13d38e80ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  sohu_news_spider    15011d40ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  sohu_news_spider    154488beac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  takungpao_spider    183df654ac3611e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  people_spider   59b99b52ac5d11e493ed0025908e45a7
ifeng_news  people_spider   5b437e94aeb911e493ed0025908e45a7
sns douban_spider   b0cebbba9a3411e493ed0025908e45a7
sns zhihu_spider    c7b866be9a3411e493ed0025908e45a7
sns douban_spider   d227a9ca9a3411e493ed0025908e45a7
sns renren_spider   df6482109a3511e493ed0025908e45a7

Running

Finished

weibo_spider    weibo_spider    a4225cb0998e11e493ed0025908e45a7        0:52:41.606361  Log Items
weibo_spider    weibo_spider    0654c0b0999611e493ed0025908e45a7        0:00:12.500178  Log Items
```

On another machine:

```
Project Spider  Job PID Runtime Log Items

Pending

Running

ifeng_news  people_spider   e791bf38b03411e49b32ac853d971155    40906   0:00:01.822573  Log Items
ifeng_news  sina_spider ce8b4754b03211e49b32ac853d971155    47189   0:15:01.822328  Log Items
ifeng_news  sina_spider ce939f26b03211e49b32ac853d971155    47280   0:14:56.822744  Log Items
ifeng_news  ifeng_spider    c8b5901cb03411e49b32ac853d971155    36879   0:00:46.823007  Log Items
ifeng_news  ifeng_spider    cecf2f76b03411e49b32ac853d971155    37129   0:00:41.822699  Log Items
ifeng_news  qq_spider   5b1f66e4aea011e49b32ac853d971155    54869   2 days, 0:15:41.822598  Log Items
sns renren_spider   6e29baeaaf6911e49b32ac853d971155    35236   1 day, 0:16:31.822673   Log Items
weibo_spider    weibo_spider    f90fce66aecd11e49b32ac853d971155    14109   1 day, 18:49:21.822745  Log Items
ifeng_news  qq_spider   04e0616aaea111e49b32ac853d971155    21047   2 days, 0:11:11.822737  Log Items
ifeng_news  qq_spider   b67686daaea011e49b32ac853d971155    12836   2 days, 0:13:11.822703  Log Items
sns renren_spider   945857f4af6811e49b32ac853d971155    33898   1 day, 0:21:06.822709   Log Items

Finished

ifeng_news  huanqiu_spider  309e0e90b03311e49b32ac853d971155        0:00:03.105042  Log Items
ifeng_news  ifeng_spider    fd4d8502b03211e49b32ac853d971155        0:01:24.509558  Log Items
ifeng_news  huanqiu_spider  30aee9e0b03311e49b32ac853d971155        0:00:02.583991  Log Items
```

the log of job 6e29baeaaf6911e49b32ac853d971155 like things below:

```
2015-02-08 16:07:02+0800 [renren_spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://browse.renren.com/s/all/ajax?q=%E9%B8%9F%E5%B7%A2&limit=100&p=&offset=600&sort=1&range=0&t=2&defaultFirst=0> (referer: http://browse.renren.com/s/all/ajax?q=%E9%B8%9F%E5%B7%A2&limit=100&p=&offset=500&sort=1&range=0&t=2&defaultFirst=0)
2015-02-08 16:07:02+0800 [renren_spider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-08 16:07:02+0800 [renren_spider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 899049,
     'downloader/request_count': 36,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 23,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 13,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 371895,
     'downloader/response_count': 36,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 23,
     'downloader/response_status_count/404': 13,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 8, 7, 2, 736353),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 38,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'request_depth_max': 6,
     'response_received_count': 36,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 36,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 36,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 36,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 36,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 8, 6, 54, 581699)}
2015-02-08 16:07:02+0800 [renren_spider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```